# Perform large batch of request to webservice from web application. Monitor progress

Tags: web-services, request, yii

I am building a web application with PHP/MySQL using the Yii framework. Key aspect of this application is to administer a large amount of entities; and perform large batches of requests to a SOAP webservice in order to update credit on these entities (cards).

I need to implement some sort of queue to manage the process of performing the batch (+/- 2000) requests.

I cannot figure out what is the best way to go;

- A background job; how to implement this with php/yii. How to give feedback to the user
- Implement a AJAX queue? Any best practices for this? Risk of interruption by closing browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue. The best way is to perform this batch in the background process. To give feedback to users, you have to write current state into your DB (e.g. into the table "batch_status"). And when user wants to see current situation, you can just retrieve data from your table. If you have some problems with implementation, you are welcome to ask me a question about it in comments ;)

To run background process in php append to your command `' > /dev/null & echo $!'`. Then execute your command: `$lastLine = exec($cmd, $output, $return_var);`. After that you get process ID in `$lastLine` variable. How to use CLI in YII you can find out here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.console

Comment: Thank you. Can you give me some guidelines to implement a background process in PHP/Yii?

Comment: Sorry for a long answer. To run background process in php append to your command `' > /dev/null & echo $!'`. Than execute your command: `$lastLine = exec($cmd, $output, $return_var);`. After that you get process ID in `$lastLine` variable. How to use CLI in YII you can find out here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.console